# Ubuntu 20 install open-weather

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, weather

I run Ubuntu 20.04.2 and I want to install open-weather,so I installed it but it doesn't seem to work.
I use this command to install open-weather:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-weather
```

then I press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> -> `r` to restart Gnome and when I open Extensions to enable and do some stuff to weather extension, I can not enable it. See screenshot in order to understand what I mean:

[image]

What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: please [edit] your question with further detail. Why did you select GNOME 3.36. I installed this extension with 20.04 and it worked straight from the tin. When you say "it doesn't seem to work" what do you mean by that? What happens? How have you configured it?

Comment: I use this command to install open-weather: sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-weather  , then I press Alt+F2 -> r to restart Gnome and when I open Extensions to enable and do some stuff to weather extension, I can not enable it.
See the following link (It's a picture-screenshot) in order to understand what I mean.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MK8NYJxyKLyitFvYI7XD2hsqWHgqdhBL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK , I did it..

Comment: Press Alt-F2, run `lg`, switch to "Extensions". look for this extension there and check the errors.